# How to get access token programatically for GCP Compute API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-authentication

I need some help for access tokens in GCP. I am using Java as program language and I tried different approaches like:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto
and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth

I am using the second approach. Code snippet:

```
 String privateKeyId = "my-private-key";

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String signedJwt = null;

    try {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, privateKey);
         signedJwt = JWT.create()
                .withKeyId(privateKeyId)
                .withIssuer("my-issuer")
                .withSubject("my-subject")
             .withAudience("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/compute.machineTypes.list")
                .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + 3600 * 1000L))
                .sign(algorithm);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return signedJwt;
```

Then I perform get instances setting the returned token as Bearer authorization header but response is:

```
 com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
     {
     "error": {
     "errors": [
       {
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "authError",
       "message": "Invalid Credentials",
       "locationType": "header",
       "location": "Authorization"
       }
       ],
       "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
       }
       }
```

With same credentials I am able to access the SDK.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that the code for a service account is not the same as the code for Oauth2 and neither are the clients that are created.

Comment: Thanks for response. This is what I am trying to figure out. How can I retrieve access token through service account?

Comment: you should be using the java client library its going to be easier and the user credentials returned will have an access token you can use

Comment: You've tagged both App Engine and Compute Engine. The answers are likely going to be different. Which platform is your code actually hosted?

Comment: My platform is Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

As per @DalmTo, you should be using the client library for Java. This is the [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) to get you started.